# Was there a specific meaning behind each child in Willy Wonka and the Chocolate Factory?

Tags: character, willy-wonka-and-chocolate-factory

Just curious if each child stood for some specific evil or something.  I feel like Augustus Gloop stood for Glutony (his name even has some similarity), but can't quite put my finger on the other kids.  Or, was there some other meaning behind each child?

Comment: I don't know direct connections for all of them but, to add to Agustus, Veruca is greed, Violet is some sort of obsession/pride... that's leading her to hunger for fame (trying to get a world record for longest chewing of a piece of gum), Mike TeaVee is sloth (? He watches a bunch of TV, anyway) and is sort of a know-it-all. To contrast, Charlie is selfless and humble... but even Charlie had some faults, to make him more human.

Comment: ... weren't there some other children in early drafts of the book, that didn't make it to the final version?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It has certainly been argued [in some quarters](http://hypervocal.com/entertainment/2012/wonka-7-deadly-sins/) that the children (and a few other character constitute the [Seven Deadly Sins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_deadly_sins):

1. Gluttony - Augustus
2. Greed - Veruca
3. Pride - Violet
4. Sloth - Mike
5. Envy - Grandpa Joe
6. Lust - Charlie
7. Wrath - Willy Wonka

Now, whether Dahl *intended* these representations to be read is another matter. I would argue Dahl simply wanted each child to be "bad" in their own way, with Charlie being our hero.

Interestingly, he originally drafted over 10 other children to be in the Chocolate Factory, before settling on the five above. Some pages from one of his manuscripts in the Roald Dahl Museum and Story Centre show his "fourth draft" of the novel's characters:

[image]

- **Augustus**: A greedy boy
- **Miranda (a character later cut from the book)**: A girl who is allowed to do anything she likes

[image]

- **Veruca Salt**: A girl who is allowed to have anything she wants. (Interestingly, note the similarity between her description and Miranda's)
- **Violet Beauregarde** - A girl who chews gum all day long.
- **Mike Teavee** - A boy who is crazy about television.

[image]

- **Charlie Bucket** - The child we like best of all

Given that there don't appear to be any interviews where he suggests links between this and the Deadly Sins or other representations of evil, it seems likely that he felt they were simply fun *bad* characters, who all had interesting flaws that would make for a good story.

Answer (score 13):

OOOH!  I think I got them all... and it's based on their last names:

- Agustus Gloop - Gluttony, like you said. [Gloop](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/gloop) is a *any thick liquid or sticky substance*... sounds like fat? He's constantly eating or complaining of hunger.
- Violet Beauregarde - Pride. [Beauregard means](http://www.sheknows.com/baby-names/name/beauregard): *Respected; regarded highly* - Violet is constantly boasting/bragging about herself and what she's accomplished and she's hungry for more.
- Veruca Salt - Greed. Salt was originally a form of money. *[Worth his salt.](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/worth-ones-salt.html)* Veruca wants everything, when she wants it... and her family gives it to her because they can afford it. She's also selfish and rude, thinking only of herself.
- Mike Teavee - Sloth. [Color TV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Television) had just become a big thing in the Early 60s, when the [book first came out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlie_and_the_Chocolate_Factory). I'm guessing this started a trend of kids sitting around a TV rather than going out to play. Mike Teavee is obsessed with watching TV.

Notice that, in each of these cases, their parents are as much the problem as the kids are.

- Agustus' parents feed him whatever he likes
- Violet's parents encourage her to win more competitions.
- Veruca's parents give her everything she demands.
- MIke's parents let him watch as much TV as he likes without trying to curb him.

Comment: I would quip that the parents *are* the problem for allowing their kids to be like this. I think the Oompa-Loompas said as much in their little songs (at least in the original). Nice answer, btw +1

Comment: I think Violet specific sin (going with your theme there) would be Pride.

Comment: @TrishLing Yeah, just having trouble reconciling her hunger for fame with pride... but she does brag a lot...

Comment: Is there any evidence from the creators that this is the case, or is this projection?

Comment: @GoodGravy I didn't really do that research, honestly. It's conjecture but it makes sense... I mean, I did research into the definition of the terminology, so I could honestly say this is an *educated* guess.

Comment: @Catija I want to believe these answers, they have a very satisfying feel and are an intelligent interpretation. However I'm not sure if we can say this is sure the case; we don't want to follow the [abbey road album cover nonsense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_is_dead#The_clues). “... we were wearing our ordinary clothes. I was walking barefoot because it was a hot day. The Volkswagen just happened to be parked there.” - Paul McCartney. My point being it is easy to project deliberation even if the effect of the creator was an accident.

Comment: @GoodGravy I'm not sure how Violet's last name could ever be an accident.  The others are more obvious but hers is really obscure. (not trying to be defensive)

Comment: @Catija Beauregarde is obscure, but it is a bona fide surname. Gloop is a far stranger name! I like this interpretation as I said, but unless the author can be found to express his intent that this was deliberate, there is inevitably still some conjecture with claims like these.

Answer (score 0):

I've watched this film many times, so I'm pretty sure that Augustus Gloop is Gluttony, Violet Beauregarde is Pride, Veruca Salt is Greed, Mike Teavee is Sloth, Charlie and his grandpa Joe are Lust and Envy respectively, and Willy Wonka himself is Wrath of course. They kind of live the Seven Deadly Sins.

Comment: What does this add to the existing answers?